# Running VISTA on H/P w/ flat panel TV for monitor. Everything perfect until I downloaded a few items

Tags: windows-vista, resolution, display

The problem: I am running VISTA on my H/P pc, which is connected to a Samsung flat panel TV.  Recently downloaded some VISTA updates and Adobe FLASH.  Now the TV, which is my monitor, has terribleresolution - and I can't change it.  It is either too large and blurry or too small and blurry.  I've tried to change to resolution in the Control Panel and have also tried to fix this using ClearType functionality.  For ClearType, I downloaded a tool from MS and that did nothing.  any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Some more information would have helped, for example which MS tool.

I suggest to use system restore to rollback your system to before the problem happened, then redoing the updates in a controlled manner, to find out which one caused the problem.

See [Using Windows 7 or Vista System Restore](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/using-windows-vista-system-restore/).